# I can't add to cart without HTTPS enabled

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a Nginx server with Varnish that runs a Drupal Commerce website. The *Add to Cart* button doesn't work on a session without HTTPS.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the *Commerce Cart* module requires a valid session or a logged-in user. The site security settings prevented sessions being sent out to HTTP requests.
While the OP solved this problem via PHP.ini, there are other valid solutions:

- Require all users to use HTTPS
- Avoid the cart is shown to anonymous users